# Recent apps getting closed without closing them

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-9, recents-screen

Samsung S9 -
In the recent apps view, the apps that were used recently are getting closed automatically.
If you do not use an app for more than one hour, then the app gets closed.

My phone forced me for an update, but after the update the apps in the recent apps view were getting closed automatically.

In the previous versions / before the update, I manually needed to close them in the recent apps.

How to prevent the apps in the recent apps not to get closed?

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Open 10 apps.
2. Go to the navigation bar.
3. Hit the recent apps button.
4. You can see the few of the applications that were used recently
5. Wait for a period of 6-7 hours/not to use the app in that time frame.
6. Most of the apps were closed automatically without closing them in the recent apps.

I found others with the same issue [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS9/comments/arh7ip/recent_apps_closing_automatically_after_pie_update/)

Comment: Basically Android is freeing up RAM space by killing the processes of unused apps. This is normal. It doesn't make sense to let an app process run for a very long time when the user is not using it actively. Why do you want to let the processes run until you close them manually? After one point of time, your phone will surely start crashing.

Comment: @WrichikBasu On of the application is a game that I was able to continue after a gap of 6-7 Hours before the update,  But now I need to work on the game from the start.  I tried to look into Device care -> memory, It only shows up to free up the ram / process used by RAM. nothing about keeping the app / process alive. even if it is not being used.

Comment: If Samsung allowed that before the update, either it was a bug, or the developers were mad. And this IS about keeping the process alive. Android automatically frees memory and kills app processes that the user has not used for long. The only way this can be changed is by the app itself. Even then, an app executing for 6 hours on the main thread is not acceptable at all.

Comment: @Wrichik Killing an app processes is common on Android, indeed. However if the OS kills an app it AFAIR remains in the recents list so that you can switch back to them. If you select such an killed app it starts again.

Comment: @Robert As far as my experience goes, selecting that app is like starting the app all over again.

Comment: Are there any official forms for Android / Pie OS where I can post this as an issue/Bug?